# How does the Android Gmail app "pin" the details view to the action bar when scrolling down the email's contents?

Tags: android, scrollview

If you view an email in the Android Gmail app you will see a details view that contains information such as date, sender, favorite indicator, etc.  This details view will "pin" to the action bar if you scroll down the email's contents.  How is this accomplished?  Below are screenshots illustrating what I am referencing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want stickyscrollview for this exact requirement - apparently from the same guy who has built the sticklistview

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is something called the "Floating header" or a "sticky header". There's a 3rd party library called [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) that you could make use.

Comment: I saw this library, but it seems tailored for ListView.  A detail page like the one pictured above wouldn't use a ListView.

Comment: True. It's meant for ListView. You could keep it as a last resort for now :P

Comment: Try this http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/smart-headers-and-footers-in-scrollviews/

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, this layout has two `ScrollView`s. The Top-most `ScrollView` handles scrolling until it has reached the farthest point it scrolls - this is the distance between your first and second images. After that point, it passes its scroll event to the lower `ScrollView` for handling.

Note that this is *not necessarily* how Google developed it - but it is an option that would work.